# Error While Read Windows Log Event in mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a web application to read all windows events log and display into the web page. i tried it in asp.net mvc 5 its working but when I tried to execute it in a asp.net mvc 6 application is shows error.

### Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.Models.PaginationExample;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application", "nb-ahja1", "EventLoggingApp");

        var model = new List<Eventlogg>();
        foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
        {
            var demo = new Eventlogg();
            demo.Source = log.Source;
            demo.Id = log.EventID;
            demo.Level = log.EntryType.ToString();
            demo.Date = log.TimeGenerated;
            demo.Category = log.Category;
            model.Add(demo);
        }
        return View(model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList());
    }


    public ActionResult About()
    {


        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

### Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Eventlogg
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

    }
}
```

### View

```html
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.Eventlogg>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container" >

    <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3"><b>Level</b></td>
        <td class="col-md-3"><b>Date</b></td>
        <td class="col-md-3"><b>Source</b></td>
        <td class="col-md-3"><b>Id</b></td>
        <td class="col-md-3"><b>Category</b></td>
        </tr>
        
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3">@item.Level</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">@item.Date</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">@item.Source</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">@item.Id</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">@item.Category</td>
        </tr>
}
    </table>

    </div>
```

### Error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EventLog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  PocDashboard.DNX Core 5.0   C:\Users\ahja\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AteaPoCDashboard\src\PocDashboard\Controllers\HomeController.cs 19  Active

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're missing an assembly reference that you need to add to your project.

'EventLog' is part of system.diagnostics namespace which is part of System.dll assembly, make sure that this assembly is referenced in your project.